# How is this binding resolved for arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

In an arrow function there is no **this** binding. So, arrow functions lexically resolve **this** reference. If we execute a function in different scope from where the function was defined, it remembers **this** reference. Does this behaviour happens due to closure ?

I know that function can remember its lexical environment by closure but in chrome developer tool **this** doesnot appear in closure but in local scope. Why does this happens ?

```
function outerScope(outerVar){
    let innerFun = () =>{
    console.log(outerVar);
    console.log(this);
}
return innerFun;
}

let innerFun = outerScope.call({test: "testing this reference"},"outerVar");
innerFun();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this behaviour happens due to closure ?

**No**

Your statement implies it's a side-effect of other mechanisms. It is deliberately part of the specification.

Section [14.2 Arrow Function Definitions](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions) deals with the subject and [14.2.17 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation) has the following note attached:

> An *ArrowFunction* does not define local bindings for **arguments**, **super**, **this**, or **new.target**. Any reference to **arguments**, **super**, **this**, or **new.target** within an *ArrowFunction* must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment. Typically this will be the Function Environment of an immediately enclosing function. [...]

(the rest of the note concerns calls to `super` and methods)

The note is not *the* definition but serves as a reminder. The rason is scattered through several different places* in the spec but the most relevant is that functions have an particular internal slot that section [9.2 ECMAScript Function Objects](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects) defines as:

| Internal Slot | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [[ThisMode]] | (lexical, strict, global) | Defines how **this** references are interpreted within the formal parameters and code body of the function. `lexical` means that **this** refers to the **this** value of a lexically enclosing function. `strict` means that the **this** value is used exactly as provided by an invocation of the function. `global` means that a **this** value of **undefined** is interpreted as a reference to the global object. |

* the "several different places" are just about arrow functions having the `[[ThisMode]]` internal slot set to `lexical`.

This is the reason arrow functions use `this` from the lexical binding at their definition place rather than closures having an effect.

It might also be worth noting that "closure" is ultimately not a very useful term in many cases - *every* function definition forms a closure. A lot of the times there the mechanism leads to nothing special, so it's not really worth discussing it. It's only interesting (and worth mentioning) when a function uses variables defined *outside of it*. The ones it "closes over":

```
const a = 42; //<--+----+
//                 |    |
function f() {//   |    |
    return a; // --+    |
}//                     |
//                      |
function g() { } // ----+
```

Both `f` and `g` will have access to the variable `a` because they are defined in the same environment - the mechanism for their creation does not change based on their body. This can be easily verified (you need to open the browser developer tools for the breakpoint to trigger):

```js
const a = 42;

function f() {
    return a;
}

function g() { debugger; }

g();
```

[image: Screenshot of the Firefox developer console running the code from the snippet above. Execution is stopped inside the body of the function g and the value of the outer variable can found in the Scopes section.]

With that said, `g` is simply not worth discussing in the vast majority of cases, as the closure mechanism doesn't have an impact.